pyarrow.__version__ error when importing pandas on jupyter notebook
I am trying to import pandas in jupyter.
I am using Anaconda on windows.
I never had a problem before on the same machine but suddenly I got an error that says :
----> 3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:22, in <module>
     19 del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
     24 try:
     25     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:20, in <module>
     14 from pandas._typing import F
     15 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
     16     is_numpy_dev,
     17     np_version_under1p19,
     18     np_version_under1p20,
     19 )
---> 20 from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
     21     pa_version_under1p01,
     22     pa_version_under2p0,
     23     pa_version_under3p0,
     24     pa_version_under4p0,
     25 )
     27 PY39 = sys.version_info >= (3, 9)
     28 PY310 = sys.version_info >= (3, 10)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pyarrow.py:8, in <module>
      5 try:
      6     import pyarrow as pa
----> 8     _pa_version = pa.__version__
      9     _palv = Version(_pa_version)
     10     pa_version_under1p01 = _palv < Version("1.0.1")`

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute '__version__

what can be the problem?
I was trying to import pandas package and expecting to be normally imported without any errors

The error message indicates that there is an issue with accessing the version attribute of the PyArrow module.
Either perform pip install --upgrade pyarrow or Reinstall PyArrow if upgrading doesn't resolve the issue.

I reinstalled anaconda and now it is all good. Nothing else worked.
